# Can I get a grammatical breakdown of どうなってんの?

Tags: grammar, translation

I have some questions about this sentence:

> まだ遅れてるって、どうなってんの？事故は昨日だったろうが。

1) Is って here an analog of のは?

2) Why is it どうなって instead of どうなった? What is an ん before の?

3) だったろう　is だろう　in past tense? Why is が　at the end of the sentence?

Comment: The なってんの here is a spoke contraction of なっているの.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. って is not simply a paraphrase of another particle. It means a quotation here, namely "*you said* it is still late, but..."

   って is not so polite a word, so yo should use this word to your friends, etc. It you need politeness, you can say まだ遅れている**というのは**、...

   Related dictionary entry for "って" (from デジタル大辞泉):

   > ［係助］名詞、名詞的な語に付く。
   >
   > 相手の質問・命令・依頼などを受けて、それを話題として示す意を表す。…と言われても。「今さら変更する―、急に困るね」「どうするか―、決まってるだろ」
2. In the phrase, どうなってんの, ん is a less-polite contraction of いる. So it's not past tense.

   The typical translation of どうなっているの is like "What's going on?"

   But often (and in this case, too) どうなってんの implies "your service is unnaturally bad."

   The reason is that from the normal meaning "what's going on?" it can deduced that "the situation is unnatural as I can't understand it."
3. Yes, だったろう is だろう in past tense. が is a 終助詞 here. 終助詞 is what is placed at the end of sentence. Quotation from the dictionary again:

   > ［終助］
   >
   > １ 言いさしの形で用いる。
   >
   > ㋐ある事柄の実現することを願う意を表す。「この風がやめばいい―」
   >
   > ㋑はっきり言うのをためらう意を表す。「こちらのほうがよろしいと思います―」
   >
   > ㋒不審の意を表す。「おかしいな、八時に集合のはずだ―」
   >
   > ２ （多く体言や体言の下にののしる意の接尾語「め」を伴ったものに付いて）ののしりの感情を強める。「このあほうめ―」「あいつめ―」

   Its exact meaning is difficult to tell. In my opinion, 1-㋒ and 2 is combined here. That is, the speaker has 不審の意 that "it's doubtful that it's still late due to the yesterday accident." and also ののしりの感情 directed to the listener.